# Pass ID once to a controller and have all controller methods remember boolean check

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I just created a simple web API using .NetCore 2.2 and Entity Framework.

I added a bit of security, by passing in a userID to each controller that the user accesses.

But I noticed that it starts getting messy when I have to add the userID to every controller in my app and the run my user check to make sure the user can access that content.

Below you'll see an example of what I mean.

I'm wondering, is there a way to add it once and then have every controller check for it?

Thanks!

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class EngineController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly engineMaker_Context _context;

    public EngineController(engineMaker_Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/Engine
    [HttpGet("{userID}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Engine>>> GetEngine(string userID)
    {
        if(!CanAccessContent(userID))
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }

        return await _context.Engine.ToListAsync();
    }

    // GET: api/Engine/123/5
    [HttpGet("{userID}/{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Engine>> GetEngine(string userID, string id)
    {
        if(!CanAccessContent(userID))
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }

        var engine = await _context.Engine.FindAsync(id);

        if (engine == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return engine;
    }

    // PUT: api/Engine/123/5
    [HttpPut("{userID}/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutEngine(string userID, string id, Engine engine)
    {

        if(!CanAccessContent(userID))
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }


        if (id != engine.ObjectId)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _context.Entry(engine).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!EngineExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }

    private bool CanAccessContent(string userID)
    {
        return _context.AllowedUsers.Any(e => e.UserId == userID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter` to check the `userID`.

1. `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter`

   ```
   public class UserIdFilter : IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
   {
       public Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
       {
           var dbContext = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
           var userId = context.RouteData.Values["userID"] as string;
           if (!dbContext.Users.Any(u => u.Email == userId))
           {
               context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
           }
           return Task.CompletedTask;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Regiter `UserIdFilter` for all action.

   ```
   services.AddMvc(options =>
   {
       options.Filters.Add(typeof(UserIdFilter));                
   })
   .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
   ```

Comment: Thanks! Would this go in the startup.cs file or any my controller?

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell Do you develop with asp.net core? You should use `services.AddMvc` in `Startup.cs`.

Comment: Yes, I am using .net core 2.2 and Entity Framework. So I'd just add your line above into my .AddMvc call?  How do I pass the acutal userId into this?  thanks!

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell Have you tried above code? First, do you get any error? What do you mean pass `userId`? As your current controller with `[HttpGet("{userID}")]`, you could pass your request with `userId` as route data. Or, you could pass `userId` as request header,  you could access request in `public Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)`

Comment: HI Tao, I'm sorry, I didn't speak correctly.  I should have asked, how would the "userId" get from the controller to the code in Startup.cs.  Thank you!

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell What do you mean by `get from the controller to the code in Startup.cs`? The `userID` is read from request, there is no relationship between `userID` and `Startup.cs`.